# How to specify an object that is of one class but not a certain subclass?

Tags: c#, oop

```
class A
{

}

class B : A
{

}

void method(A that is not a B argument) {}
void generic_method(generic_class<A that is not a B> generic_argument) {}
void params_method(params A that is not a B[] params_arguments) {}
```

Is there any syntactical way to do this? i realize that i could just do

```
if(argument is B)
    throw new ArgumentException("argument cannot be a B", "argument");
```

at the beginning of the first method, and do that in a foreach for the second and third, but I'm wondering if there is some keyword or OOP concept that accomplishes this better.

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to do this, you should ask yourself, why? It appears you want to break the idea that a `B` is an `A`.

Comment: A class should not be aware of its sub-classes and should certainly not forbid it without an extremely specific and good reason. There is no such constraint in C# because that wouldn't really make sense. Would you mind shedding more light on the problem you're trying to do this to solve?

Comment: You might want to create a `RealA` that inherits from `A` (which may now be abstract) and continue to have `B` inherit `A`. You now know that `RealA` and `B`, though related by `A` (for whatever reason) are not assignable, and then change your signatures to expect `RealA`s where you don't want `B`s.

Answer (score 8):

So it sounds like you're trying to express the *opposite* of a constraint such as:

```
var Foo<T>() where T : SomeClass
```

That would constrain `T` to be `SomeClass` or a subclass<sup>1</sup>... but you're trying to make it explicitly *not* a `T`.

No, I'm afraid there's no such constraint in C#.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, modulo the assumption that `SomeClass` is a class to start with; it could be an interface, with the meaning you probably expect.

Answer (score 7):

No such constraint exists in C# because it's a bad idea, specifically its a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles)

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming. It states that, in a computer program, if `B` is a subtype of `A`, then objects of type `A` may be replaced with objects of type `B` (i.e., objects of type `B` may be substituted for objects of type `A`) without altering any of the desirable properties of that program

If your program explicitly *rejects* objects of type `B` then that's clearly a violation of the LSP and a strong indication that you are doing polymorphism wrong - probably `B` shouldn't inherit from `A` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Of course interface would be better in this case in my opinion:

```
public abstract class A1
{
  //shared things for A and B 

  public string Hello()
  {
     return "hello!";
  }
}

public class A : A1
{

}

public class B : A1
{

}

public void something(A foo)
{
   var bar = ((A1)foo).Hello(); // says hello
}
```